# Are object initializations in Java "Foo f = new Foo() " essentially the same as using malloc for a pointer in C?

Tags: java, c, object, memory, memory-management

I am trying to understand the actual process behind object creations in Java - and I suppose other programming languages.

Would it be wrong to assume that object initialization in Java is the same as when you use malloc for a structure in C?

Example:

```java
Foo f = new Foo(10);
```

```
typedef struct foo Foo;
Foo *f = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
```

Is this why objects are said to be on the heap rather than the stack? Because they are essentially just pointers to data?

Comment: Objects are created on the heap for managed languages like c#/java. In cpp you can create objects on the stack just as well

Comment: Why did the creators of Java / C# decide to exclusively store objects on the heap?

Comment: I *think* for the sake of simplicity. Storing objects on the stack and passing them a level deeper involves copying the object on the stack, which involves copy-constructors. I didn't google for a correct answer, but I'm sure you can find a more satisfying answer yourself (or somebody else will elaborate on this side question)

Comment: @Jules objects in java could still be "decomponsed" at run-time (called `scalar-replacement`) into just plain fields that live on the stack only; but that is something that `JIT` does, not `javac`.

Comment: “heap” is just a name for a set of properties associated with allocated objects/memory. In C/C++ you can select from two different sets of properties, called “stack” and “heap”, in C# and Java, all object allocations have the same specified behavior, which goes under the name “heap”, which doesn’t imply that these properties are the same as for the C/C++ “heap”, in fact, they aren’t. This doesn’t mean that implementations can’t have different strategies for managing the objects, it implies that those strategies are irrelevant to the application logic.

Answer (score 5):

In C, `malloc()` allocates a region of memory in the heap and returns a pointer to it.  That's all you get.  Memory is uninitialized and you have no guarantee that it's all zeros or anything else.

In Java, calling `new` does a heap based allocation just like `malloc()`, but you also get a ton of additional convenience (or overhead, if you prefer).  For example, you don't have to explicitly specify the number of bytes to be allocated.  The compiler figures it out for you based on the type of object you're trying to allocate.  Additionally, object constructors are called (which you can pass arguments to if you'd like to control how initialization occurs).  When `new` returns, you're guaranteed to have an object that's initialized.

But yes, at the end of the call both the result of `malloc()` and `new` are simply pointers to some chunk of heap-based data.

The second part of your question asks about the differences between a stack and a heap.  Far more comprehensive answers can be found by taking a course on (or reading a book about) compiler design.  A course on operating systems would also be helpful.  There are also numerous questions and answers on SO about the stacks and heaps.

Having said that, I'll give a general overview I hope isn't too verbose and aims to explain the differences at a fairly high level.

Fundamentally, the main reason to have two memory management systems, i.e. a heap and a stack, is for *efficiency*.  A secondary reason is that each is better at certain types of problems than the other.

Stacks are somewhat easier for me to understand as a concept, so I start with stacks.  Let's consider this function in C...

```
int add(int lhs, int rhs) {
    int result = lhs + rhs;
    return result;
}
```

The above seems fairly straightforward. We define a function named `add()` and pass in the left and right addends.  The function adds them and returns a result.  Please ignore all edge-case stuff such as overflows that might occur, at this point it isn't germane to the discussion.

The `add()` function's purpose seems pretty straightforward, but what can we tell about its lifecycle?  Especially its memory utilization needs?

Most importantly, the compiler knows *a priori* (i.e. at compile time) how large the data types are and how many will be used. The `lhs` and `rhs` arguments are `sizeof(int)`, 4 bytes each.  The variable `result` is also `sizeof(int)`.  The compiler can tell that the `add()` function uses `4 bytes * 3 ints` or a total of 12 bytes of memory.

When the `add()` function is called, a hardware register called the *stack pointer* will have an address in it that points to the top of the stack.  In order to allocate the memory the `add()` function needs to run, all the function-entry code needs to do is issue one single assembly language instruction to decrement the stack pointer register value by 12.  In doing so, it creates storage on the stack for three `ints`, one each for `lhs`, `rhs`, and `result`.  Getting the memory space you need by executing a single instruction is a massive win in terms of speed because single instructions tend to execute in one clock tick (1 billionth of a second a 1 GHz CPU).

Also, from the compiler's view, it can create a map to the variables that looks an awful lot like indexing an array:

```
lhs:     ((int *)stack_pointer_register)[0]
rhs:     ((int *)stack_pointer_register)[1]
result:  ((int *)stack_pointer_register)[2]
```

Again, all of this is very fast.

When the `add()` function exits it has to clean up.  It does this by subtracting 12 bytes from the stack pointer register.  It's similar to a call to `free()` but it only uses one CPU instruction and it only takes one tick.  It's very, very fast.

---

Now consider a heap-based allocation.  This comes into play when we don't know *a priori* how much memory we're going to need (i.e. we'll only learn about it at runtime).

Consider this function:

```
int addRandom(int count) {
    int numberOfBytesToAllocate = sizeof(int) * count;
    int *array = malloc(numberOfBytesToAllocate);
    int result = 0;

    if array != NULL {
        for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            array[i] = (int) random();
            result += array[i];
        }

        free(array);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Notice that the `addRandom()` function doesn't know at compile time what the value of the `count` argument will be.  Because of this, it doesn't make sense to try to define `array` like we would if we were putting it on the stack, like this:

```
int array[count];
```

If `count` is huge it could cause our stack to grow too large and overwrite other program segments.  When this *stack overflow* happens your program crashes (or worse).

So, in cases where we don't know how much memory we'll need until runtime, we use `malloc()`.  Then we can just ask for the number of bytes we need when we need it, and `malloc()` will go check if it can vend that many bytes.  If it can, great, we get it back, if not, we get a NULL pointer which tells us the call to `malloc()` failed.  Notably though, the program doesn't crash!  Of course you as the programmer can decide that your program isn't allowed to run if resource allocation fails, but programmer-initiated termination is different than a spurious crash.

So now we have to come back to look at efficiency.  The stack allocator is super fast - one instruction to allocate, one instruction to deallocate, and it's done by the compiler, but remember the stack is meant for things like local variables of a known size so it tends to be fairly small.

The heap allocator on the other hand is several orders of magnitude slower.  It has to do a lookup in tables to see if it has enough free memory to be able to vend the amount of memory the user wants.  It has to update those tables after it vends the memory to make sure no one else can use that block (this bookkeeping may require the allocator to reserve memory *for itself* in addition to what it plans to vend).  The allocator has to employ locking strategies to make sure it vends memory in a thread-safe way.  And when memory is finally `free()`d, which happens at different times and in no predictable order typically, the allocator has to find contiguous blocks and stitch them back together to repair heap fragmentation.  If that sounds like it's going to take more than a single CPU instruction to accomplish all of that, you're right!  It's very complicated and it takes a while.

But heaps are big.  Much larger than stacks.  We can get lots of memory from them and they're great when we don't know at compile time how much memory we'll need.  So we trade off speed for a managed memory system that declines us politely instead of crashing when we try to allocate something too large.

I hope that helps answer some of your questions.  Please let me know if you'd like clarification on any of the above.

Comment: `int` is not 8 bytes on a 64-bit platform. It's still 4. Along with that, the compiler is very likely to optimize the third `int` out of the stack into the return register. In fact, the two arguments are also likely to be in registers on any 64-bit platform.

Comment: I've edited my answer to remove the statement about 8-byte `int`s on 64-bit platforms.  You are correct that `int` remains 4-bytes in Java.  I've left the remainder of my answer however because I believe getting into compiler optimization puts the cart before the horse.  Yes you are also correct on these points, but the *question* asks for clarification on stacks vs. heaps.  RVO, argument passing via registers, code elision, etc. overburdens the basic concepts and gets in the way of understanding the fundamentals.